# JavaFX generalization from 2 to n

Tags: javafx

The following algorithm draws one wandering particle. By a duplication of code, a second particle was added. So, I imagined that a loop would make a generalization to n particles. But I have been unable to produce n-independently moving particles. How can I achieve that?

```
    public class Particle extends Application 
    {
        //Create animation

        private final SequentialTransition animation

                        = new SequentialTransition();

        //Turn on  the random generator     

        private static final Random r  = new Random();

        private static double radius = 10;

        //Jumps are tiny
        private static    double deltaX = 0.01;
        private static    double deltaY = 0.01;
        //Direction of movement = (tx,ty)
        private static int tx = 0;
        private static int ty = 0;

        //Time is discrete
        private static int t = 0;

        //Change movement?
        private static  boolean changeX;
        private static  boolean changeY;
        //Flip direction?
        private static int signX = 1;
        private static int signY = 1;


        private void init(Stage primaryStage) 
        {
            Group root = new Group();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
            Circle circle = new Circle(400,400,radius);
            root.getChildren().addAll(circle);



            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            //This is a JavaFX loop
            timeline.setCycleCount(70000);

            timeline.getKeyFrames().add
            (
                new KeyFrame
                (Duration.millis(0.25)
                        , (ActionEvent actionEvent) -> 
                    {                                 
                        //Recurrent jumps
                        circle.setTranslateX(
                            circle.getTranslateX() + signX*deltaX*tx);
                        circle.setTranslateY(
                            circle.getTranslateY() +  signY*deltaY*ty);
                        //Random number, functions like a coin
                        t = r.nextInt(700);
                        if ( t == 1) changeX = true;
                        //Change x-component of velocity
                        if (changeX)
                        {
                            tx = r.nextInt(10);
                            signX = -signX;
                            changeX = false;
                        }
                        t = r.nextInt(700);
                        if ( t == 1) changeY = true;
                        //Change y-component of velocity
                        if (changeY)
                        {
                            ty = r.nextInt(10);             
                            signY = -signY;                        
                            changeY = false;
                        }                                      
                    })
            );
            animation.getChildren().addAll(timeline);

        }



        public void play() 
        {
            animation.play();
        }

        @Override public void stop() 
        {
            animation.pause();
        }    

        @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
                throws Exception 
        {
            init(primaryStage);
            primaryStage.show();
            play();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just create a list of n particles and in the KeyFrame's action loop over that list and modify coordinates of all the particles.

Comment: There is a particle sample (fireworks) as part of the Ensemble sample application for JavaFX.  You might want to review the [fireworks source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/tip/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/graphics2d/canvas) to see how it is implemented (note that sample uses a canvas for rendering rather the scene graph).